# Magento2: Set NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW for 404 page not found

Tags: magento2, 404-page, robots.txt

How to set NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW for 404 page.

I've added below xml from admin no-route page.

```
 <reference name="head">
        <action method="setRobots"><value>NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW</value></action>
    </reference>
```

But it will only work for `domain.com/no-route` but it should work for all pages which not available on site ex. `domain.com/psdfsdf`

Answer (score 4):

Edit cms page in that Design >  Layout Update XML add like below:

```
<head><meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW"/></head>
```

Comment: I've already tried it. its only work for no-route page. if you check other page which is not available on website. its show 404 but robots doesn't get from here

Comment: that is different from what you have written there is not live  <reference name="head">  here is direcrly <head>

Comment: This does not work in Magento2.2.3, you get an error that says 

`Please correct the XML data and try again. Element 'head': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( referenceContainer, container, update, move ). Line: 1`